# How to save selected values from string (spinner) to sqlite

Tags: android

So I tried to implement a new spinner to get a new value on my code. I already put the value in the res/strings, and it is working well. There is no problem with the EditText values, but I'm confused on where to put the spinner code. So I get the selected values into the 6th value on my sqlite.

Or if there is any unnecessary code, let me know.

Here is my code:

```
public class DataPeserta extends AppCompatActivity {
protected Cursor cursor;
datpes dbHelper;
Button ton1, ton2;
EditText text1, text2, text3, text4, text5;
Spinner spNamen;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_data_peserta);

    dbHelper = new datpes(this);
    text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    text3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    text4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    text5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    spNamen = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_cbng);
    ton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    ton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);


    ton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            db.execSQL("insert into biodata(no, nik, kpj, nama, nohp, cabang) values('" +
                    text1.getText().toString() + "','" +
                    text2.getText().toString() + "','" +
                    text3.getText().toString() + "','" +
                    text4.getText().toString() + "','" +
                    text5.getText().toString() +  "')");


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Berhasil Daftar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            MainMenu.mm.RefreshList();
            finish();
        }
    });
    ton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
spNamen.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

**EDIT**

```
public class DataPeserta extends AppCompatActivity {
protected Cursor cursor;
datpes dbHelper;
Button ton1, ton2;
EditText text1, text2, text3, text4, text5;
Spinner spNamen;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_data_peserta);

    dbHelper = new datpes(this);
    text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    text3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    text4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    text5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    spNamen = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_cbng);
    ton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    ton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    String[]   cabangArray =getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Cabang_Pelayanan);           

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cabangArray);

    spNamen.setAdapter(adapter);



    ton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            db.execSQL("insert into biodata(no, nik, kpj, nama, nohp, cabang) values('" +
                text1.getText().toString() + "','" +
                text2.getText().toString() + "','" +
                text3.getText().toString() + "','" +
                text4.getText().toString() + "','" +
                text5.getText().toString() + "','" +
                spNamen.getSelectedItem().toString() +  "')");


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Berhasil Daftar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            MainMenu.mm.RefreshList();
            finish();
        }
    });
    ton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

**Query**

```
db.execSQL("insert into biodata(no, nik, kpj, nama, nohp, cabang) values('" +
                    text1.getText().toString() + "','" +
                    text2.getText().toString() + "','" +
                    text3.getText().toString() + "','" +
                    text4.getText().toString() + "','" +
                    text5.getText().toString() + "','" +
                    spNamen.getSelectedItem().toString() +  "')");
```

Comment: I've tried that one before and still had no idea why it didn't worked

Comment: I just realized this... I mean did the spinner needs a code to read the values itself?

Comment: I saw `cabangArray` there... What does it stands for? and anyway I've tried that one and still didn't worked when I press the submit btn

Comment: Are you add this line in database query. `spNamen.getSelectedItem().toString()`

Comment: Did it looks goood? `@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String sql = "create table peserta(no integer primary key, nik integer null, kpj integer null, nama text null, nohp integer null, cabang text null);";
        Log.d("Data", "onCreate: " + sql);
        db.execSQL(sql);`

Comment: Umm sorry sir but I didn't see any differences from your latest answer... The code already listed below `SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();`

Comment: I mean it's already listed here `SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            db.execSQL("insert into biodata(no, nik, kpj, nama, nohp, cabang) values('" +
                text1.getText().toString() + "','" +
                text2.getText().toString() + "','" +
                text3.getText().toString() + "','" +
                text4.getText().toString() + "','" +
                text5.getText().toString() + "','" +
                spNamen.getSelectedItem().toString() +  "')");`